# iOS - animation resize object in one axis

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I am trying to resize my column created in Storyboard. I am new in this and for now I get this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                          delay:0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         CGAffineTransform scaleTrans = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 6);
                         CGAffineTransform moveTrans = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -200.0);
                         MyColumn.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(scaleTrans,
                                                                           moveTrans);
                     }
                     completion:nil];
}
```

It's changing object and at the end it looks ok (it's where object originally starts and with 6x times bigger height). Problems are:

- Animation isn't starting where is object but somewhere at the bottom of the screen.
- I want to have option to set exact column height size and have option to start from 0 height (now I have set 20 height for testing)

I know that if I want to fix second problem I shoudn't use scale transform but I tried these:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0
                     delay:0.0
                     options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         MyColumn.bounds = CGRectMake(150, 150, 150, 150);
                     }
                     completion:nil];

[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect theFrame = AnswerAColumn.frame;
                         theFrame.size.width += 50.f;
                         MyColumn.frame = theFrame;
                     }];
```

and I just can't get it working (it doesn't change anything). What am I doing wrong? Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting the CGAffineTransform out of the animation block and then just setting it inside the block?

Comment: It didn't change anything. It's working same as before.